# Convert objects and functions to valid JavaScript source code?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a JavaScript object that looks something like this:

```
{ bacon: [Function], hello: [Function], tables: [Function] }
```

Where `[Function]` is an actual JavaScript function.

I want to write this to a `.js` file with contents like:

```
var Templates = /*source code here*/
```

How can I get the source code for the object and function properties as a string, such that eval'ing this "source code string" will give me back the same object?

Comment: I don't think I understood your requirement

Comment: Have you tried calling `toString` on the function? For an object you could just use a JSON parser.

Comment: `.toString()` also gives back "[object Object]"

Comment: `.toString()` seems to work on the functions actually, but not on the object.

Comment: Saying that you want the "source code" for an object has no meaning. Objects do not have source code. If you want the ability to easily recreate the object by *executing* some code, then you should use JSON.

Comment: @ChrisHayes: Why doesn't it have meaning? Let me rephrase then: I want a string such that calling `eval()` on it will yield *exactly* the same object. JSON cannot represent functions.

Comment: I have since created [js-serialize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-serialize) if anyone else is looking for this functionality. There's a few other variants on npm too if you hate me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I rolled my own serializer:

```
var templates = { /* object to stringify */ };
var properties = [];
_.each(templates, function(value, key) {
    properties.push(JSON.stringify(key)+': '+value.toString());
});
var sourceCode = 'var Templates = {' + properties.join(",\n") +'};';
```

This gives me back:

```
var Templates = {"bacon": function anonymous(locals, attrs, escape, rethrow, merge) { ... },
"hello": function anonymous(locals, attrs, escape, rethrow, merge) { ... },
"tables": function anonymous(locals, attrs, escape, rethrow, merge) { ... }
};
```

(snipped bodies for brevity)

Comment: I was actually writing something like this up.  Glad you figured it out though.

Comment: This should work, but don't use _ if the question wasn't tagged as such.

Comment: Eval'ing the toString representation of a function is not going to work all the time. Closure state will be lost for one thing. There may be other issues too?

Comment: @Bart: I'm OP... I have access to underscore.

Comment: @hifier: Yes....there are definitely issues. If you look at the output I posted, that's definitely not the full source of the function, because when I execute those functions they do something different. I'm trying to figure that out now.

Comment: Why do you ask questions that can be answered easily by yourself? And why don't you at least say 'thanks' to guys that tried to help you?

Comment: @hek2mgl: Because I didn't know the answer at the time I asked this question, and the other commenters/answerers guided me in the right direction, even if they didn't put it all together. They suggested using `.toString()` on the function, and Bart pointed out why objects can't be cast to strings, which lead me to the conclusion that I'd have to serialize the object myself but could toString the function.

Comment: then you should consider to upvote or accept one of these posts

Comment: @hek2mgl: Ok, you guys can have upvotes. I was hesitant, because pretty much everyone outright ignored the serializing the object part.

Comment: @hek2mgl: It is, thank you. I can't accept my own answer for 2 days though.

Answer (score 2):

In Javascript a function is an object. The `Function` object supports the method `toString()`. This will actually give you the source code of a function. Like this:

```
function foo() {
    var a = 1 + 1;
}

alert(foo.toString()); // will give you the above definition
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're trying to say, this would show me the function code:

```
myObj = {

    myMethod: function() {
        console.log("This is my function");
    }
}

console.log(myObj.myMethod.toString());
```

Comment: I need the entirety of `myObj`, not just one property.

Comment: @Mark You could run a loop of some kind to get the source for all of them.

Comment: Curly braces, and property names included. I guess I could write that part of the string by hand, but I don't quite understand why I can get the source for a function but not the object part.

Comment: That's probably because an object can have a reference to itself. You can't serialize recursive objects.

Comment: @Bart: That's a good point. In this scenario, however, I don't, but that would explain why this may not be implemented.

Comment: hehe :) For me,the question was a little bit too localized as I had no time to have really a look into. Is the question resolved or do you need further help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JSON.stringify](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc836459%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) to accomplish this via the `replacer` argument:

```
var myObj = { a  : 1, b : function(val) { doStuff(); };

var replacer = function(key, val) {
      return "key : " + val.toString();
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(myObj, replacer));
```

I haven't tested this but the idea should be sound.

Comment: Running that verbatim (aside from a missing curly brace), I get back `"key : [object Object]"`. It still can't serialize the object.

Answer (score 0):

If you may want to use node.js, you can use a lib that can handle ASTs.
You may have a look at https://github.com/substack/node-falafel

Comment: I'm really not sure how this is helpful. It looks like it lets you manipulate the AST once you have the source code. I was having trouble getting the source code in the first place, and I don't need to manipulate after I do have it.